# iOS Audio Streamer for iOS7

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming, avplayer, audiostreamer

I am looking for a way to stream live audio within iOS7. Before, I used Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer but now pretty much all the method's are deprecated and so I am looking for a new way. Does anyone know any path's I can take? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adjustable, it is based on Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer but a more recent version [adjustable](https://github.com/tumtumtum/audjustable)